# jQuery Fade out Transparency In IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, transparency, opacity

I'm working on a site and I have run into a few problems. [Here](http://wesbos.com/tf/shutterflow/?cat=1) is the site

1. I have two divs. `.slide` and `.cover`.

`.cover` fades in and out when hovered over displaying some text and a transparent background. This is done with jQuery and the transparency is with CSS.

This works fine on load in all browsers but when I hover over a slide and it fades back in, the background transparency of `.cover` doesn't work in IE (6 7 and 8). I've tried css with `.cover:hover` and that doesn't work as an IE hack.

```
.cover {

    width:750px;
    height:500px;
    background:#000;
    margin:0 auto;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    }
.cover:hover {  opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery you could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide').hover(
        function() {  $(".cover").animate({ opacity: 0.7 }, 500 ); },
        function() {  $(".cover").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500 ); }
    );
});
```

and remove this from your CSS:

```
.cover:hover {  opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);}
```

Comment: That coupled with my old code worked great. Did not remove CSS